how to find where my Junit4 dependency was brought in at a Maven project?
I've migrated my Maven project from Junit4 to Junit5, and removed this line:
<junitVersion>4.9</junitVersion>

from my pom.xml file.
But somehow, I'm still able to use this
import org.junit.Test;

in my code, I'd like to know which one of my libs brought Junit4 in as transitive dependency.
I used mvn dependency:tree, here's what I have and I don't see Junit4 anywhere:
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.7.16:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.7.16:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.16:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.30:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:compile (version managed from 1.2.0)
[INFO] |     +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

JUnit brings it. The documentation says Instead, JUnit provides a gentle migration path via a JUnit Vintage test engine which allows existing tests based on JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 to be executed using the JUnit Platform infrastructure. Since all classes and annotations specific to JUnit Jupiter reside under the org.junit.jupiter base package, having both JUnit 4 and JUnit Jupiter in the classpath does not lead to any conflicts. It is therefore safe to maintain existing JUnit 4 tests alongside JUnit Jupiter tests.

Thanks, does this mean there's no way to prevent using Junit4 in my project? I've removed org.junit.vintage dependency also in my pom.xml, and I'm still able to resolve Junit4.

I'm not really certain. Nor am I certain why you are worried about transitive dependencies. This is specifically for unit tests. They are intended to test your artifact. They aren't typically considered deliverables. I've been using TestNG for a while. Sorry.

The line junitVersion does not define something from spring boot... the property is name  junit.version furthermore that will only define a version with a depenendecyManagement part of the spring-boot-dependencies but does not use as a dependency.. So there must be some dependency which is using it directly or as a transitive depenendency. If you have defined the junit-vintage-engine that is the point where the dependency is comming from... So you have to remove the dependency to junit-vintag-engine

Your dependency tree doesn't show Junit4 org.junit JAR. If you can still use it in the IDE try to update Maven and clean up the project.

you could try ctrl-click on the "import org.junit.Test" line in eclipse, that will open the Test class and then in the project explorer you can see which jar it's coming from.
